# Python regular expression issues

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to get better at python in general but I'm having some trouble using the re module for regular expressions.

I have a comma separated csv file that I'm reading in, and then I want to find all occurrences of a line ending in a comma 5. So I used the code below:

```
    five_rating = re.compile(r",5$", re.MULTILINE)
    print five_rating.findall(file.read())
```

but I don't get any output. There are definitely occurrences that match the regular expression I'm using, I've tested my regex on python regex websites and they model what I want, but in code, it just doesn't work!

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Oh and I'm using Ubuntu and the file should have DOS style line endings, but I tried converting the end-line characters using the code from [this post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66434-change-line-endings/) and it didn't do the trick.

btw here's a sample of the input:

```
9605,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9606,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
9607,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9608,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9609,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9610,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9611,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9612,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9613,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9614,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9615,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9616,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
9617,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9618,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9619,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9620,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
9621,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9622,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9623,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9624,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9625,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9626,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9627,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9628,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
```

Comment: A regex is probably overkill for this particular problem. [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) would do it nicely. For more on python regexes you can see the [howto in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: How did you open `file`? Also note that [**`file`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) is a Python built-in and therefore a bad choice for an identifier. Personally I would use [**`str.endswith()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) for this task (unless you want to extract data from the CSV, in which case the [**csv**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module is a better approach.

Comment: While regular expressions have their uses (particularly in text editors themselves) they're often abused in code and scripts where a plain expression is as good and more readable.

Comment: I actually used str.endswith() initially, but it wasn't returning results oddly enough....

Since this was a short little assignment I decided to stick to my tiny python book to figure out how to parse the file as opposed to scouring the internet...although unfortunately it wasn't enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you input (which could be a file) as a multiline string, like this:

```
st='''9605,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9606,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
9607,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9608,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9609,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9610,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9611,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9612,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9613,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9614,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9615,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9616,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
9617,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9618,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9619,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9620,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1
9621,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9622,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9623,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5
9624,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9625,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,2
9626,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,4
9627,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,3
9628,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,1'''
```

This works:

```
import re

for line in st.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'(^.*,5$)',line)
    if m: print m.group(0)
```

or a `re.findall` version:

```
print re.findall(r'(^.*,5$)',st, re.MULTILINE)
```

or (somewhat confusingly IMHO) re.findall will work without parens:

```
print re.findall(r'^.*,5$',st, re.MULTILINE)
```

Yours is not working because of no `.*` meaning 'match everything up to the ',5$'

Also as stated in one of the comments, using `file` as a identifier is a bad idea.

You can also use Python's string processing to do this:

```
for line in st.splitlines():
    if line.endswith(',5'): print line
```

And if you really have a CSV file to process -- use the builtin CSV module.

---

Finally -- if you have a DOS file on *nix, just use Python's [universal line](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) support by using [open with 'U'](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) in it:

```
with open(...,'rU') as infile:
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't really need a regex here:

```
with open('file') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip().endswith(',5')]

print(list(lines))
>>> ['9605,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5', '9613,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5', '9614,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5', '9623,Ace Ventura: Pet Detective,5']
```